# TFS branch strategy with Build and InRelease

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, ms-release-management

I look at the best way/strategy to use TFS/Build/InRelease for an existant project (was in VSS).

The "worst" scenario (has happened previously) :

```
            Main
2.0 -------------------------------------------->

Release 3.0 |------------------------------------|

Release 2.1    |----------------------|

Release 2.0.1        |---|

3.0 : take 120 days start at day 1
2.1 : take 30 days start at day 20 (to day 50)
2.0.1 : take 2 days start at day 30
```

At first I look at https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

So I made something like this :

```
/MySystem
/MySystem/[Main]
/MySystem/Release 2.0.1
/MySystem/Release 2.0.1/[Service]
/MySystem/Release 2.0.1/[Release]
/MySystem/Release 2.1/[Service]
/MySystem/Release 2.1/[Release]
/MySystem/Release 3.0/[Service]
/MySystem/Release 3.0/[Release]

Service is a branch from Main. 
Release is a branch from Service.
You should use Release for builds definitions.
```

With this strategy, I need a new build definition for each release and edit the release template in InRelease (or create a new template)

It take several time to make a build definitions but I think it worth the risk.

Colleagues proposed to use 4 lines (Main, Major, Minor, Hotfix), each have a build and a release template.

That will look like this :

```
 /MySystem
    /MySystem/[Main]
    /MySystem/Dev
    /MySystem/Dev/[Major]
    /MySystem/Dev/[Minor]
    /MySystem/Dev/[Hotfix]
```

Using Label for versions. You need to understand label and not forget how you use it and to USE IT(new guy often just create a new branch somewhere).

If I want full branch for each version :

```
 /MySystem
        /MySystem/[Main]
        /MySystem/Release
        /MySystem/Release/[Major]
        /MySystem/Release/[Minor]
        /MySystem/Release/[Hotfix]
        /MySystem/Service
        /MySystem/Service/Version 2.0.1
        /MySystem/Service/Version 2.1
        /MySystem/Service/Version 3.0
```

This one is a little more complicated because when you want to create a new service, you need to update the good release version and create a new branch with this one. You shouldn't change parent.

---

each strategy work. Witch one I should use? Maybe you have something better­.

Comment: Are you actually using InRelease still? If so, it's high time you transitioned to the rebranded Microsoft version, since there have been numerous improvements in the past 2 years. And I say this as someone who works for the company that originally wrote InRelease.

Comment: Yes we are using InRelease. Its not on my power to go on the microsoft version. I search the best way to use it. Merci